# Matrix of a linear transformation with respect to a different basis

Tags: linear-algebra

A linear transformation $A: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ has in a basis $B= \{(1,2,1), (2,1,1), (1,0,0)\}$ a matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Find a matrix of the linear transformation in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R^3}$

I have first tride calcuating: $A(1,2,1) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
1
\end{bmatrix} = (2,2,1)$, and by the similar process: $A(2,1,1) = (2,1,-1), A(1,0,0) = (2,0,0)$

Since the standrad basis of $\mathbb{R^3}$ is $\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$, I've expressed the previous calculated vectors with linear combinations of basis vectors of $\mathbb{R^3}$, but got stuck here not knowing what to do next.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just Take A as a matrix as unknown in 9 variables and solve !!!

Comment: What does it mean if A has this matrix in an basis B?

Comment: Well!!! First what is a Basis?(I hope you know!!!) It means simply that Applying A  on that Basis B we get the matrix you have written!! Now if u see each element of the Set B are columns which are linearly independent!!!

Comment: I do know what a basis is. And thank you, i understand it better now, that if A has a matrix in a basis B, applying A on a basis B will give us a matrix with columns as the calculated vectors. I'm just having trouble finding a matrix in a different basis, and i'm probably missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your matrix is diagonal, so your basis is formed by eigenvectors. So the matrix P formed by the vectors of your basis verifies that $$PAP^{-1}$$ is the matrix respect the canonical basis